# Swift Using NSFetchedResultsController and UISearchBarDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uisearchbar

I am looking for a decent solution to this problem. I am wanting to implement some simple search functionality on a TableView that I have.

All the examples I have found either use the deprecated `UISearchDisplayController` or use the new `UISearchController` but without `NSFetchedResultsController`
Currently this is populated using `Core Data` / `NSFetchedResultsController`

So far I have managed to get it to a point where I can gather the users' search string (woo!). I am aware that I may need a separate `FRC` to perform the search on, but as mentioned above all attempts up to now have failed.

My class is conforming to the following protocols:

```
class JobListController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate{
```

I can't use `UITableViewController` as I have already written loads of existing functionality that relies on this class being a `UIViewController`
 I have my two `IBOutlets`:

```
@IBOutlet var tblJobs : UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
```

and my empty arrays to hold my various `Core Data` bits and bobs:

```
var workItems = [Work]()
var filteredWorkItems = [Work]()
```

Here is how I am initialising my `FRC`, along with my `MOC` and I've left in my empty second `FRC` as I am quite sure it will be needed at some point:

```
  let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let workFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Work")
    let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdDate", ascending: true)
    let secondarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "town", ascending: true)
    workFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor, secondarySortDescriptor]

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: workFetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!,
        sectionNameKeyPath: "createdDate",
        cacheName: nil)

    frc.delegate = self


    return frc
    }()

var searchResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?
```

In my `viewDidLoad` function I am setting up the delegates / data source for my table and the searchBar:

```
  tblJobs.delegate = self
  tblJobs.dataSource = self
  searchBar.delegate = self
```

and here is the `searchBar` function which is where I am up to. The `stringMatch` variable is leftover from a previous attempt, I am hoping to be able to search by a multitude of different parameters here, but if I can get just one working it will be a solid start.

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    println("Search text is \(searchText)")
    self.filteredWorkItems = self.workItems.filter({( work: Work) -> Bool in
        //
        let stringMatch = work.postcode.rangeOfString(searchText)
        return stringMatch != nil
    })

    if(filteredWorkItems.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tblJobs.reloadData()
}
```

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function to show how I am pulling data from the `fetchedResultsController`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell =  self.tblJobs.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
        "JobCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        as! JobTableViewCell

    let workItem = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Work



 //...

    return cell
}
```

So you can see I've got a few things going on here, ultimately I am wanting to figure out how I use my newly gotten `searchText` string to query against my `FRC`, and then for the results to filter properly in the View.

**Update:**

I have attempted to add the search string to my `NSPredicate` in the `FRC` like so:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {

   ../


    workFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"title contains[cd] %@", savedSearchTerm!)

   //...
    return frc
    }()
```

Which results in `'JobListController.Type' does not have a member named 'savedSearchTerm'`

At the top of my class I have set it up like this:

```
var savedSearchTerm: NSString?
```

So not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your code, I assume you want to use the **same** table view to display the results. So you just need to update your FRC with a new filter based on the search term.

Store the search term in a variable. In the FRC factory function, include the predicate, something like this:

```
request.predicate = searchText?.characters.count > 0 ?
 NSPredicate(format:"title contains[cd] %@", searchText!) : nil
```

When the text changes, reset the FRC and reload.

```
fetchedResultsController = nil
tableView.reloadData()
```

If you have additional filters, such as scope buttons, add additional terms to the predicate.

Comment: are there any advantages to using a separate table view? I can't visualise how having a separate table view would work?

Comment: Usually it is a somewhat transparent overlay table view which is superimposed. This can be useful if you use custom cells that do not display the rich data in your original table view but, say, just the text that is being searched for.

Comment: ii'm having a couple of issues with this, firstly I can't access my searchTerm variable from inside my lazy var fetchedResultsController, also I can't set that fetchedResultsController to nil

Comment: You don't have to set the NSFetchedResultsController to nil. Reset the predicate with: fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate. Then call self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error) to requery.

Comment: Maybe you want to check out UISearchController and see if it's more to your liking. You are able to completely create it from code.

Comment: I tried to implement it but it relies on UITableViewController not UIViewController doesn't it?

Comment: @Mundi Once again, you've helped get me over the finish line on something. Thank you for posting!

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**

This is a working solutions from one of my app. I have trimmed it down to make it simple to show how it works.

I have a database of around 6000 rows in which I search via 3 different scopes: Notes, Author and Keywords. I call `initializeFetchedResultsController` in the `viewDidLoad` function with default values. And later when user starts typing in the Search field, start calling it again with the required value.

**The Fetch part:**

```
let EMPTY_STRING = "" // I don't like string literals in my code so define them as static variables separately

// Giving two default values
func initializeFetchedResultsController(_ text: String: EMPTY_STRING, _ scope: Int = 0) {
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: NotesAttributes.author.rawValue, ascending: true)]
            if searchedStringTemp != EMPTY_STRING { // Whatever conditions you want to pass on
                let p0 = NSPredicate(format: NotesAttributes.scope.rawValue + " != \(scope)")
                let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "\(column) CONTAINS[cd] %@", "\(text)")
                fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [p0, p1])
            }

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: AppDelegate().sharedInstance().persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do {
        try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print("Error 12312: Unable to Perform Fetch Request")
        print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

**The search controller:**

```
// MARK: - UISearchBar Delegate
extension AllNotesVC: UISearchBarDelegate {
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    // This is my function which I call to start search
    notesSearched(searchBar.text!, searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
}
}

// MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate
extension AllNotesVC: UISearchResultsUpdating {
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    let text = searchController.searchBar.text!
    let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
    // This is my function which I call to start search
    notesSearched(text, scope)
}
}
```

And this in my `notesSearched` method which re-initialize the fetch results controller and reload the table every time.

```
// MARK: - Private instance methods

private func notesSearched(_ text: String, _ scope: Int) {
    initializeFetchedResultsController(text, scope)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

While calling doing so many table reloads might not be the most efficient way to do this, but it is lightening fast, and since this updates the table in real-time as user is typing it provides a wonderful user experience.